# IE10 <br> elements show unknown character icon

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, page-break

I have a site which, in ie10 ONLY is showing `<br>` and `<br />` tags and diamonds with question marks (unknown character icons).  I have changed char encoding (everything is UTF-8), DOCTYPE declaration (currently `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` ), meta http-equiv to all version and edge.

Again, I only have this problem in IE10 as far as I can tell.  I have tried Chrome, Firefox and Safari also.

Has anyone experienced this also, or possibly have suggestions as to what might fix it.  For now, I have simply removed the insert BR function in the WP add P tags for content filtering, and removed brs from the templates and other php generated html.  This is not ideal for me or my client for multiple reasons, and I really would like to triumph over this stupid problem  :)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose its something with file encoding, post html code you use?

Comment: We might need the URL too, or you would need to provide the HTTP headers as sent by the server.

Comment: Need to see the site. The CSS too; it's possible to give many nasty styles to `br` elements. this is WordPress, right? Was it a standard template, or did it have lots of customisations?